# Using SOCKS proxy from BSD connect level

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, proxy, socks

I am working with some network code on my client that connects to a server using BSD-level socket APIs (connect(), etc.). My program is written in Objective-C and platform is iPhone

I want to add SOCKS-proxy support to this, but I have not been able to find any way to do this at the BSD level. I have seen code that does this at the CFNetwork level, but I'd rather not rewrite all my networking code for this.

If anyone knows how I can add SOCKS client support at the BSD level, please let me know.

UPDATE: I am pretty sure I could implement the SOCKS protocol myself, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Is there any 3rd party libraries that are recommended for this (hopefully open source)? They would have to be able to plug into my existing BSD-level socket code.

Comment: did u found the solution boss??